# What is the difference between 「進行」 and 「進歩」?

Tags: word-choice, usage, nouns

What is the difference between 「進行」and「進歩」？ In what situations are they used ?

Comment: proceed — 進行 — progress — 進歩 — advance(ment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- 進歩 is advancement to a higher/better/improved stage. Mainly used with scientific/technical ideas. 科学の進歩, コンピュータの進歩, 進歩したエンジン.
- 進行 is:

  - progress to a advanced (often worse) stage: 癌の進行, 環境破壊が進行した
  - progress of a plan, procedure, task, etc: 予定の進行, 結婚式の進行, 研究の進行状況
  - running/moving of a train, car, etc: 列車の進行, 進行方向の安全確認